# Retrive Names from table with age above 20 and display them in listBox

Tags: c#

I have difficulties with my program. i have a dataGridView filled with values from my access database.I also have a listBox just placed under the dataGridView.In my dataGridView i have name_Columns,Contact,age,status etc.The difficulties i have is , to display in the list box the names of people with age above 20 only so i don't know how to do that.I will be very happy for any assistance from you.I've inserted an image and some code I've already done.
thanks

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //View items in the Data Grid 
    {
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        string query = "select * from DataPay";
        cmd.CommandText = query;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        adap.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();

    }
```

[image: Click to view image]

Comment: Why don't you change your OleDb query to `string query = "select * from DataPay where Age>20";`?

Comment: Start with : List<string> names = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("Age") > 20).Select(x => x.Field<string>("Name")).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the condition `WHERE` clause like

```
string query = "select * from DataPay where Age > 20";
```

Comment: The above code is to fill the datagridView. i have not yet code the query to fill the list box with age above 20. i will try to add this to my query >string query = "select * from DataPay where Age > 20";>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [RowFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the DataView. You can set this property directly on the DataTable retrieved but this will also filter the DataGridView. If you want to keep the two controls separated with separated content then you can create a new DataView using the original table as source of data for the new DataView

```
    ....
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    adap.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    con.Close();
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt, "Age > 20", "Name", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
    listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
    listBox.DataSource = dv;
}
```

Comment: Please can i make the condition where the listbox displays the names where Datetime.today - DOB is greater than 20?

Comment: @RahimPameloMarakashNdane why would you want to do that, you have already calculated the Age in the database?

Comment: yes that's true , But in the case i want to have the duration of an event that is, DateTime.today - Date of the event > 100 days . and the bring out the event concerned in a listbox.. that is what i want to do

Comment: You can put any expression in the second parameter for the Dataview constructor allowed by the syntax explained in the [DataColumn.Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property